# Java Android Error: Class is Abstract Can't Be Instantiated

Tags: java, android

I have this class that I want to instantiate, but I can't because it gives an error that the class is an abstract while it's not.

```
    public class Comment {

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("postedBy")
    private Map<String, String> postedBy = null;
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("content")
    private String content = null;
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("location")
    private String location = null;


    public Map getPostedBy() {
        return postedBy;
    }

    public void setPostedBy(Map postedBy) {
        this.postedBy = postedBy;
    }


    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }


    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

Instantiating it:

```
Comment c = new Comment();
```

It gives error that

```
'Comment' is abstract; cannot be instantiated
```

Comment: Check your imports, you're probably trying to instantiate another class named `Comment` from a different package

Comment: Do you by any chance have two classes named Comment? Check if you are trying to instantiate the right one.

Comment: You guys are correct there is a different class named Comment in a different package. Please any one can make it the answer so I can accept it. Thank you